# How to improve the performance of querying WmiMonitorBrightness?

Tags: c, wmi

I have a dll for controlling brightness of integrated monitor by using WMI.
I ran into a trouble that sometimes the query method takes longer than 600 ms to get a IWbemClassObject. A normal condition is taking less than 50 ms.

```
HRESULT WMIQueryBrightness()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    BSTR QueryLanguage = SysAllocString(L"WQL");
    BSTR QueryTarget = SysAllocString(L"SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorBrightness");

    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    hr = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        QueryLanguage,
        QueryTarget,
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnum);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        WMIDestroy();

        return hr;
    }

    hr = pEnum->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pClsWmiMonitorBrightness, &uReturn);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        WMIDestroy();

        return hr;
    }

    SysFreeString(QueryLanguage);
    SysFreeString(QueryTarget);

    return S_OK;
}
```

I tried to clarify which function takes too much time and found that pEnum->Next() sometimes takes longer than 500 ms. However, I do not know how to improve this situation.
Could you give me some ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Profile the system. You are accessing a shared resource on a multitasking system.

Comment: I do not know what does "Profile the system" mean. Could you give me more information about that?

Comment: You profiled your application to determine that a system call has highly variable timing.  Now profile the system and look for correlations.  What else is going on that could cause a performance hit?  [Google Perfmon](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=qv_5WbrZFcHSjAPlq4X4BA&q=perfmon&oq=Perfmon&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l10.1236.3186.0.6437.8.7.0.0.0.0.89.423.7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.7.423.0..0i131k1j0i131i46k1j46i131k1.0.FRzfXohtH2k)